# custom style for react Quill package

Tags: javascript, reactjs, quill

Is it possible to add a custom style like this, on React js:

```
const style = {
"& .ql-snow .ql-stroke": { stroke: "white" },
};
<ReactQuill
    theme="snow"
    value={contentText}
    onChange={setContentText}
    modules={modules}
    style={style} />
```

I need to access the `.ql-snow .ql-stroke` class and add the stroke key.
I am trying to figure it out in different ways without results, as CSS or entering the DOM like:

```
const qlstroke = document.getElementsByClassName(".ql-stroke");
//Here goes the function to change the stroke key, but I don't know how
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yaa you can 
I did the same with **tailwind**

[example code Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tr98d.png)

[output image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WNK5A.png)

[Overall code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i8GCf.png)

You can customize more by going through there default snow.css file to overwrite the css (**control + click** the snow.css file to know more )

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).